# writing to columns in same row in csv file (python)

Tags: python-2.7, csv

Im trying to write values to a csv file such that for every two iterations, the result is in the same row and then the next the values print to a new row. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
import math
savePath = '/home/dehaoliu/opencv_test/Engineering_drawings_outputs/'

with open(str(savePath) +'outputsTest.csv','w') as f1:
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
        temp = []
 for k in range(0,2):
        temp = []            
       for i in range(0,4):
            a = 2 +i
            b = 3+ i
            list = [a,b]
            temp.append(list)
       writer.writerow(temp)
```

The result I am getting now is

```
[2 3][3 4][4 5][5 6]
[2 3][3 4][4 5][5 6]
```

But I would like to get this (without the brackets) where each number in a row is in a separate column:

```
2 3 3 4
4 5 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import csv
import math
savePath = '/home/dehaoliu/opencv_test/Engineering_drawings_outputs/'

with open(str(savePath) +'outputsTest.csv','w') as f1:
        writer=csv.writer(f1, delimiter='\t',lineterminator='\n',)
        temp = [2, 3]
        for i in range(2):
            temp = [x + i for x in temp]
            additional = [y+1 for y in temp]
            writer.writerow(temp + additional)
            temp = additional[:]
```

This should return:

```
# 2    3    3   4
# 4    5    5   6
```

You start with a temporary containing the numbers `2` and `3`. Then, you loop from `0` to `2` (excluding). At every iteration, you increment the values of the temporary by the current index and subsequently create an additional list with these new values of your temporary list. Once that's done, you join the two lists together and write the result out to your file. At this point, you can set your temporary list to be equal to the values of the additional list, before moving on to the next iteration.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way you present it you can do it with a simple seed and increment:

```
import csv
import os

save_path = "/home/dehaoliu/opencv_test/Engineering_drawings_outputs/"

with open(os.path.join(save_path, "outputsTest.csv"), "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n")
    temp = [2, 3, 3, 4]  # init seed
    increment = len(temp) // 2  # how many pairs we have, used to increase our seed each row
    for _ in range(2):  # how many rows do you need, any positive integer will do
        writer.writerow(temp)  # write the current value
        temp = [x + increment for x in temp]  # add 'increment' to the elements
```

Resulting in:

```
2   3   3   4
4   5   5   6
```

But if your seed is: `temp = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]` and you decide to generate 4 rows, it will still adapt:

```
2   3   3   4   4   5
5   6   6   7   7   8
8   9   9   10  10  11
11  12  12  13  13  14
```